# rollback package version in spacemacs

Tags: emacs, version, package, rollback, spacemacs

During the initial `spacemacs` setup where a completion framework is selected (`helm` or `ivy`), packages are installed by default. In the past and at present, a bug exists in one of these packages, removing `auto-completion` functionality.

My question is: How do I scale back the bugged package version in `spacemacs` so that this functionality returns? I'm aware a similar question exists for vanilla `emacs` but I want to make sure I haven't missed any nuances that might exist in `spacemacs`.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I always recommend placing your (working) emacs config under version control, so that you know you always have a functional configuration to install from. If you update one or more packages and something breaks, you simply revert to the previous state.

Comment: @phils is 'your (working) emacs config' defined as `~\.spacemacs`/`~/.emacs` and `/path/to/.emacs.d/elpa/*` ?

Comment: @phils actually I think I've got it - going to make one repo for `.spacemacs` and another for `.emacs.d`

Comment: Everything is inside `~/.emacs.d` for me, so it's that one directory. Use `~/.emacs.d/init.el` rather than `~/.emacs`. I don't use spacemacs, but I *assume* that it also enables you to use a file under `~/.emacs.d` rather than one in your home directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clone package repo (package url ends with `.git`):

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/<package-name>.git
```

Checkout to older version, before bug.
Check for older commit:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/package
git log
```

Checkout:

```
git checkout <commit hash>
```

Copy older package version to local `elpa` location (`package-directory` will contain a date in the string):

```
/bin/cp -f /path/to/cloned/package/* /path/to/.emacs.d/elpa/<package-directory>/
```

Remove compiled files:

```
rm -f path/to/.emacs.d/elpa/<package-directory>/*.elc
```

Open up emacs, check for absence of package bug:

```
emacs
```